# How do I get this loop multiply until a certain limit?python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the task: Write a function that has a limit(lim) and Returns `prod` and `Count`, where prod is defined as  `(1+1/1**2)(1+1/2**2)(1+1/3**2)`...
Count is amount of times it has ran. It supposed to end when prod is less than the limit. this is what I got so far: (I fixed the code With the help I got from the responses)

```
def variabel(n):
return 1+1/n**2
def tol():
tol1 = float(input("Hva er grensen?"))
prod = 1
prod2 =2
prod3 = 2
n = 1
count = 0
while tol1 < prod2:
    prod3 = variabel(n)*prod
    prod2 = prod3-prod
    prod = prod3
    n += 1
    count += 1
    if tol1 >= prod2:
        print("Produktet ble", prod, "etter", count, "itterasjoner")
tol()
```

Comment: This looks like Norwegian homework to me. Is it?

Comment: `prod = (1+(1/n**2))` overwrites `prod` for each iteration, so all other lines that change `prod` don't have any effect

Comment: change that line to `step` instead of `prod` an i think it will work

Comment: yes, it is the norweigian homework.

Answer (score 2):

first a hint that will help you solve this type of problem and  help keep your code nice and neat.

1. break your code into smaller sub problems, and create a helper method for each subproblem

   problem 1: solve 1/n**2 in generic way

   ```
   def default_function(x):
       return 1/x**2
   ```

   problem 2: create a series from this

   ```
   def my_series(start=1,func=default_function):
       #return 1/n**2 for ever 
       for i in itertools.count(start):
           yield func(i)
   ```

this lets you try various things for example if i wanted to print the values forever

```
for value in my_series(): # will print forever...
    print(value)
    time.sleep(1)
```

if you just wanted the first 10 values

```
for i, value in zip(range(1,11),my_series()):
    print("{0}. {1}".format(i,value))
```

if you wanted to plot the first 100 values

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
xs_and_ys = zip(range(1,101),my_series()) #[(1,series[0]),(2,series[1]),...]
xs,ys=zip(*xs_and_ys) # transpose into separate xs and ys
plt.plot(xs,ys)
plt.show()
```

now you will notice i didnt quite finish your homework for you, instead i hope that ive given you the tools that you can use to solve your 3rd subproblem

problem 3: return series until the product of them is greater than or less than some threshold

Comment: It's good to see decomposition being encouraged. If only more people did this as a matter of course in their answers!